# MS Access Linked Tables - Drive Name Changes Based on Location

Tags: ms-access, linked-tables

I have an Access database, split into two. One is the front end with all objects, linked to the other database - containing the tables. Both are in the same folder. Locally, the drive is G:. In our other office in another city, the drive is also G:. However, when a colleague in the other office opens the front end database, he gets an error message that it cannot connect locate the G:\ drive for the linked tables. I think there's a difference in the drive name. I know I can add VBA upon the database opening to change the link to that of the current folder. However, if two people in different offices are using the database at the same time, I think that will cause problems as each user would need a different link. Any suggestions will help!
Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Are users sharing their front-end? That's a bad practice and can lead to trouble.

Comment: Each user should run their own copy of the frontend installed on their local workstation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the tables to the explicit folder path. Or the UNC address. It would start with \servername\folder...

I have done this several times, but, access will run very slowly across large distances and outside of a LAN. I would reccomend importing the table if it is used for reference, and create a copy within the front end. Of course, have the front end located on the users PC for fastest accessibility and response. If you are actively working with records in the table, use a query to add and edit records in the table instead of a bound form. Otherwise everything will slow down.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. 
If I'm making copies on each user's machine, when would the records update to the original table? 
In your second suggestion, would I be running VBA after finished entering/editing a record to "Insert Into" or "Update" the original table?

Comment: @jsic1210 if you put a save button on the form and update statement behind the button you would be able to update the source table specifically when the user wanted to send the update to server. Otherwise, none of their changes would save. I have found this method speeds up the connections substantially. And also allows you to bypass the 255 concurrent user limit. Because if they're all working off of a local copy of the table, and not actually connected to the real server.